# Converting a decimal number to binary in PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

I have this function which converts numbers from decimal to binary.

```
<?php
function DecimalTOBinary($num)
{
    $a = "";
    $b = "";
    $x = 0;
    while ($num !=0)
    {
        $b .= $num % 2;
        $num = $num /2;
    }
    /*
    for($i = strlen($b) -1;$i >=0;$i--)
    {
        a .= substr($b,$i,$i +1);
    }*/
    return $b;

}
?>
```

My problem is that it will return the string:

```
010010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I wish to return only:

```
0100101
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

`$num = $num / 2;` probably does fractional division (implicitly converting to *float*), causing `$num` to approach `0` but taking a very long time to get there. Make it `$num = floor($num / 2);` to round it back down to an *integer*.

Note that there's also [`decbin()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php), the built-in method for achieving this.

---

Exemplary (but superfluous):

```
function DecimalTOBinary($num)
{
    return decbin($num);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want that function for practical reasons, do what @Core Xii says. If you want to implement that function to learn, you should use the [`floor`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) function: `$num = floor($num/2)`, because PHP thinks that `$num` is a float and doesn't divide it as an integer.

Also, you'll want to `return strrev($b)`, because your digits will be reversed.

Answer (score 0):

This function will do what you want:

```
<?php
function DecimalToBinary($num) {
    $i = "";
    while (floor($num) > 0) {
        $i .= $num % 2;
        $num /= 2;
    }
    return strrev($i);
}
```

The main changes are:

- Flooring the number in while loop check
- Reversing digits.
- Removed unnecessary variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code this solution done with recursive function:

```
 function getBinary($num) {
 $remainder = '';
 $remainder = $num % 2;
 $num = floor($num / 2);  
 if ($num>=1)
  {
    $remainder .= getBinary($num);
  }
  
 return $remainder;
} 
echo getBinary(10);
```

Comment: It's best to explain your answer